# Уничтожение потоков DELPHI

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Добрый вечер.
Такой вот вопрос, почему не удаляются потоки? Они останавливаются да, но они не исчезают и они не работают, откуда я знаю почему они не исчезают?

Открываем Диспетчер задач=>Быстродействие, там внизу есть кнопочка "Монитор ресурсов..." Откроется окошечко, в нём выбираем ЦП (вторая вкладка) ищу название своей проги(ну когда ее запустишь разумеется, там появится `Projec1.exe`)

Потом, я жму старт потокам, они создаются видно как цифра увеличивается в колонке потоки до 200+, жму кнопку стоп, которая выполняет `counth := 1` всё... потоки остановились, прога ничего не делает И по идеи там в мониторинге потоки должны исчезнуть!!! Но этого не происходит! Почему?! ВСЕ варианты из гугла по уничтожению потоков испробовал, подскажите что можно сделать???

Почему они не хотят удаляться я же сказал им `Free`))

```
type
    TTH = class(TThread)
      protected 
      //constructor create(CreateSuspended:Boolean);
        procedure Execute; override;
    end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    .........................
  end;

var
    Form1: TForm1
    CS : TCriticalSection;
    Threads: TTH;
    counth:integer;

{
 constructor TTH.create(CreateSuspended:Boolean);  { ТЕСТИЛ }
 begin
 //  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
     inherited Create(false);
     FreeOnTerminate:= true;
 end; 
 }


procedure TTH.Execute;
begin
    CS.Enter;
    sleep(500);
    if counth = 1  then begin
       // exit; ПО ИДЕИ ДОЛЖЕН ПРОСТО ВЫЙТИ И УНИЧТОЖИТЬ СЕБЯ ТАК КАК СТОИТ Threads.FreeOnTerminate:= true; НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!
       Terminate;  // Threads.Terminate;    Такие варианты тоже пробовал 
       WaitFor;   //  Threads.WaitFor;
       Free;    //   Threads.Free;
    end;
    Synchronize(Work);
    CS.Leave;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
    for i := 1 to 200 do begin
        Threads := TTH.create(false);
        Threads.FreeOnTerminate:= true;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    counth:=1;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    CS:= TCriticalSection.Create;
end;
```

Comment: Мне кажется что поток сам семя из памяти не вычистит и free нужно вызывать из вне. Создайте коллекцию потоков и после нужные убирайте.

Comment: `freeOnTerminate` там вроде был, не?

Comment: Был был `Threads.FreeOnTerminate:= true;` и в `constructor ` тоже ставил, по идеи там в `execute` когда условие идёт на exit оно же должно себя само убить так как ПО УСЛОВИЮ потоки выполнили свою задачу, но нет!

Comment: поясните, почему вы думаете, что потоки не завершаются, и в чем смысл вашей переменной `counth`.

Comment: вы переопределите деструктор потока, чтобы он в memo какой-нибудь, через `synchronize`  отчитывался о завершении.

Comment: c `FreeOnTerminate` поток должен завершиться самостоятельно, без всяких ваших `free` (которые не надо бы вызывать внутри себя самого), `terminate` и т.п.

Comment: Я от безысходности `Free` вставлял везде где можно, почему я знаю что потоки не уничтожились? Потому что в "Мониторинге ресурсов" написано 200+ потоков, а если дать проге закончить свою работу, они все удаляются, это видно `if counth = 1  then begin
    exit; end;`  Почему потоки всё равно не уничтожаются, цикл же прекратился, условие выполнено, а `FreeOnTerminate:= true;`

Comment: я почему спросил про `counth`, ибо оно тут в коде фигурирует 2 раза, один в проверке на 1, а второй в присвоении этой единицы. потоки мгновенно там у вас не остановятся, т.к. они в критической секции, то они проходят ее по одному с паузой в 0.5сек. А монитор ресурсов это не то средство, которым надо узнавать число запущенных потоков, имхо. И что у вас  в процедуре `work`, поток же ее выполняет, мб там и застревает где нибудь.

Comment: В процедуре work всё ок, там всего 1 строка кода все потоки по очереди заходят в критическую секцию и выполняют `sleep` после `sleep` они идут в `exit` так как кнопка стоп делает глобальную переменную `counth = 1` работа программы прекращается, процедура work не выполняется больше.

Comment: а критическую секцию кто, вася пупкин, покидать будет? у вас туда первый поток зашел, заблокировал ее, завершился, и все. остальные 199 стоят и ждут пока секция освободится. и еще у вас 1 основной поток приложения есть. вот вам и 200 штук в мониторе.

Comment: `if counth = 1  then begin exit`   если `counth = 1` тогда `exit` и так по очереди для каждого потока который входит в критическую секцию, они же не ждут, не стоят там, перед входом в критическую секцию

Comment: а для чего критическая секция по вашему вообще нужна? именно то и делают, что стоят и ждут.

Comment: попробуйте не жать свою кнопку, чтобы условие `counth` не выполнялось, тогда раз в 500мс число потоков будет уменьшаться (если время выполнения work не значительно)

Comment: Если условие if не выполнять (не жать на кнопку) потоки конечно уменьшаются. 
 
Я только что пробовал ставить условие if до и после критической секции код просто выполняется дальше, я в критической секции делаю условие чтобы процедура остановила своё выполнение и уничтожила поток и по идеи они после входа в критическую секцию должны по условию отправится на exit, не так ли? Чего им ждать перед критической секцией я же им не запрещаю в нее входить?

Comment: вы поняли, что критическая секция это *механизм блокировки потоков*, и что если туда вошел один поток, то другие ждут. А если один поток зашел, и забыл выполнить `cs.leave()`  то все остальные навеки останутся ждать? Блок кода между `enter/leave` может выполнятся только одним поток одновременно, для этого они сделаны в принципе.

Comment: Ха, а вот так я не думал попробовать и даже не знал что `CS.Leave;` можно прописать несколько раз и не будет ошибки)) Решение проблемы `if counth = 1  then begin  CS.Leave;   exit;     end;` спасибо))

Comment: куда практичнее будет `try if .... then exit; finally cs.leave() end;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши проблемы происходят из-за непонимая назначения и способа работы критических секций. Критическая секция, реализуемая классом `TCriticalSection` это один из механизмов синхронизации потоков между собой. Суть этой синхронизации в данном случае в том, чтоб блок кода, расположенный между входом в КС и выходом из нее может одновременно выполняться только одним потоком.
Вот схематический пример:

```
cs.enter();
try
   doSomething();
finally
    cs.leave();
end;
```

Когда вы запускаете несколько потоков, выполняющих этот код, то первый поток который входит в секцию блокирует ее и работает. Второй поток, который чутка не успел, выполняет метод `cs.enter()`, а дальше происходит чутка магии. Секция захватывает второй поток и приостанавливает его работу, ставя его в очередь, пока первый поток не покинул секцию.  То же самое происходит и с остальными потоками, они тоже становятся в очередь.
Как только первый поток выполняет инструкцию `cs.leave()`, тот второй поток вновь продолжает работу. Остальные также ждут своей очереди

В своем коде вы искусственно создаете ситуацию, когда поток входит к критическую секцию и выходит из процедуры, забыв покинуть секцию. То есть у вас происходит `exit`  из процедуры без вызова `cs.leave()`.
Таким образом, все остальные потоки остаются захваченными критической секцией и ждут доступа в нее, чего никогда не произойдет поскольку поток-косячник уже давно завершился и разрушился. Секция не получает никаких уведомлений, о том, что поток внезапно умер. Ответственность за блокировку и освобождение секции лежит полностью на ваших плечах.

---

#### Дополнение:

Согласно замечанию к ответу, очередность выбора следующего потока для входа в критическую секцию не  определяется порядков FIFO *(first-in first-out, первым зашел, первым вышел)*. Такой порядок использовался в win XP, и win2003 server:

> Starting with Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1 (SP1), threads
> waiting on a critical section do not acquire the critical section on a
> first-come, first-serve basis. This change increases performance
> significantly for most code. However, some applications depend on
> first-in, first-out (FIFO) ordering and may perform poorly or not at
> all on current versions of Windows
> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:**  Threads that are waiting on a
> critical section are added to a wait queue; they are woken and
> generally acquire the critical section in the order in which they were
> added to the queue. However, if threads are added to this queue at a
> fast enough rate, performance can be degraded because of the time it
> takes to awaken each waiting thread.

*[источник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)*

*Текст ответа вверху не исправляю, поскольку он проще для объяснения принципа работы. Но надо понимать, что очередности тут какой-то строгой нет, и планировщик может учитывать различные факторы, в т.ч. приоритеты потоков.*

Comment: `тот второй поток вновь продолжает работу. Остальные также ждут своей очереди` - не совсем так, это было правдой до WinXP включительно. Тут вступает в силу магия планировщика потоков. Какой поток он выберет для просыпания после высвобождения cs - этого никто предсказать не может. Принцип "первым вошел в ожидание - первым вышел" не действует более...

Comment: @kami спасибо за замечание. Дополнил ответ.